# Axioms for 2-forms, why should $\omega_x(\Delta x \wedge \Delta x) = 0$

Tags: integration, differential-forms

I am having trouble understanding this piece about 2-forms from Terence Tao's "Differential Forms and Integration".   I understand the bilinearity requirement in analogy to the one-dimensional case.  But I don't understand the last axiom (8).   Why should it be zero?

$\omega_x(\Delta x \wedge \Delta x) = 0$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.  Normally we have two different arguments delta1 x and delta2 x.  They are both vectors and represent the sides of a parallelogram extending from our base point.  So if delta1 x = delta2 x then the sides are the same and so the parallelogram is "collapsed" and has no area at all.  Then it is clear there should be no "flux" through such a parallelogram.  This explains why it should be zero.

Comment: Yes, I like to think of k-forms as a measure of a k-dimensional extent in some higher dimensional space. In this instance there was a 2-form and 2 copies of the same line has no two dimensional extent. I know we are saying the same thing but seeing each others slightly different perspectives often broadens our own.

Answer (score 0):

$\Delta x\wedge \Delta x =0$

$\omega(\Delta x\wedge \Delta x)=\omega(0)=\omega(0 \Delta x)= 0\omega(\Delta x)=0$

Comment: okay, but why is the wedge of the two delta x's zero in the first place?  The wedge was introduced in Tao's paper as a "meaningless placeholder" so it is not at all clear to me why that should be zero.